# Did not know the name when exporting

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem when I try to change the name of the download when exporting to PNG, JPEG, PDF and SVG, it does not make the change, it appears to me only as chart

this is my code I use version 11.2...
I want to know if a highcharts problem or am I doing something wrong

````
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Corn vs wheat estimated production for 2020',
        align: 'left'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text:
            'Source: <a target="_blank" ' +
            'href="https://www.indexmundi.com/agriculture/?commodity=corn">indexmundi</a>',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['USA', 'China', 'Brazil', 'EU', 'India', 'Russia'],
        crosshair: true,
        accessibility: {
            description: 'Countries'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '1000 metric tons (MT)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' (1000 MT)'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Corn',
            data: [406292, 260000, 107000, 68300, 27500, 14500]
        },
        {
            name: 'Wheat',
            data: [51086, 136000, 5500, 141000, 107180, 77000]
        }
    ],
    exporting: {
        enabled: true,
        filename: 'descaga_prueba' // specify the filename here
    },
});```
````

Comment: It's a bug that should soon be fixed. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/20370

Comment: The bug is in highcharts' serverside, so there's nothing we can do about it in from client side. However, as mentioned in the issue, the `offline-exporting` module is working if you need a temporary workaround.